# How to stop Repeated Audio play in Audio Mixer (MixerHost) for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have got Audio Mixer(MixerHost) sample code from Apple iOS. This code is working fine. 
It is playing the sample Audio files continuously. Can you tell me how to stop my Mixer code to stop after playing audio once?

Is it possible disable repeated play using `AVAudiosession`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this method?

```
// Handle a play/stop button tap
- (IBAction) playOrStop: (id) sender
```

Answer (score 0):

In MixerHostAudio.m, inside the inputRenderCallback method, just comment the line

> if (sampleNumber >= frameTotalForSound) sampleNumber = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this inputRenderCallback as below:

```
if (sampleNumber >= frameTotalForSound) {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTI_AUDIO object:nil userInfo:nil];
     return noErr;
}
```

The NSNotification "NOTI_AUDIO" just let the viewcontroller know when the audio is stopped.

Hope this helps!